# Sigma Notation Evaluation without Harmonic Numbers

Tags: calculus, summation

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left (\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{k}{l(l+1)} \right )\end{align*}$$

I'm trying to evaluate this problem, and I can't find a way to get started (without using harmonic numbers). Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: i have got $\frac{n^2}{2}$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner The answer depends on both $n$ and $m$.  If $n=m$, then yes, the answer in your comment is correct.  Otherwise, it is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\frac{1}{l(l+1)}=\frac{1}{l}-\frac{1}{l+1}$$
we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{m}\left(\sum_{l=1}^{n}\frac{k}{l(l+1)}\right)&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}k\sum_{l=1}^{n}\left(\frac 1l-\frac{1}{l+1}\right)\\&=\sum_{k=1}^{m}k\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\end{align}$$
I think you can continue from here.

Comment: All to easy ... +1

Comment: yes i have made a typo the right result is $$1/2\,{\frac {mn \left( m+1 \right) }{n+1}}$$